# Segmentation fault when using nanosleep()

Tags: c, types, sleep, long-integer, time.h

```
$ ls
baby.txt      readlyrics.c
```

I tried to write a simple program to print the text from a .txt file using **nanosleep()** to get some sort of animated effect:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *target_file = argv[1];
    char *sec     = argv[2];
    char *nsec     = argv[3];

    int   tv_sec  = atoi(sec);
    float tv_nsec = atof(nsec);

    struct timespec *t;
    t->tv_sec  = tv_sec;
    t->tv_nsec = (long)(tv_nsec * 1000000000);

    FILE *content = fopen(target_file, "r");
    int *c  = malloc(sizeof(char));
    c       = NULL;
    c = fgetc(content);
    while(c) {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = NULL;
        nanosleep(t, NULL);
        c = fgetc(content);
    }
    fclose(content);

    return 0;
}
```

And got an error:

```
$ ./read ./baby.txt 0 0.01
zsh: segmentation fault  ./read ./baby.txt 0 0.01
```

Which part of the code went wrong?

Comment: Build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building). Then run in a debugger to catch the crash and locate exactly where in your code it happens. Then you can also examine variables and their values to see if they give come hints.

Comment: By the way, all your fidling with `c`, making it a pointer, and all its reassignment, and then treating it as an actual `char` instead of a pointer to one, that tells me that you need to spend more time with your text-books to read about pointers, and more importantly read about `fgetc` and what it returns. You seem to have some basic misunderstanding about reading characters from files.

Comment: `while(c)` is wrong. `fgetc` does not return `0` or `NULL` at end of file. You need to declare `c` as an `int` and compare it against `EOF`. Note that `EOF` is generally defined as `-1` and hence evaluates to true when used in a boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer now...
Aside from variable **c**, I declared **t** as a pointer and it was not initialized, after changing `struct timespec *` to `struct timespec`  I solved the problem.
I think it's because it relies on the user's input to get itself initialized.

Comment: The whole mess with `c` overshadowed that you use the pointer `t` without making it point anywhere. But this issue would have been found out by enabling more warnings when building, as GCC typically is able to catch such problems.